# Problem with getpwuid() and stat()

Tags: c, posix

I have the following code. It gives me a problem with free memory, but I haven't figured out what exactly the problem is. It seems that `getpwuid(buf->st_uid);` is not getting along with `readdir(dirh);` or with stat functions. Does anyone know why?

```
buf = (struct stat*) malloc(sizeof(struct stat));        
for (dirp[i] = readdir(dirh); dirp[i] != NULL; dirp[++i] = readdir(dirh)){

    ptr=(char *)malloc(sizeof(strlen(mydir)));

    ptr=strdup(mydir);
    strcat(ptr,dirp[i]->d_name);

    stat(ptr,buf);
    //modos();

    getpwuid(buf->st_uid);
    printf("\t%s\n",ptr);

    //we free the buf memory
}

free(buf);
closedir(dirh);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't allocate enough space for the string.

You do an unorthodox length calculation which ignores the actual length of 'mydir'; you then make a good copy of the directory name (but leak the memory previously allocated); you then concatenate the name over the end of the space allocated by `strdup()`, which is always bad.  If you omitted the `sizeof()`, then you would be allocating one byte too few for a null terminated directory string.

You also should not cache the separate return values from `readdir()` because it generally returns a pointer to the same bit of memory each time.  You are certainly not authorized to assume that it does otherwise.

You are also trampling over freed memory if you really release buf inside the loop; you allocate just once, and free many times.

Normally, you would not bother to allocate the `buf` at all; it is not that big a structure.

You also don't self-evidently have a slash separator between the directory name and the file name component; that might not matter if you've ensured that `mydir` has one on the end.

---

Here is a simple program that more or less does what is necessary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    static const char mydir[] = "./";
    DIR *dirh;
    size_t dlen = strlen(mydir) + 1;

    if ((dirh = opendir(mydir)) != 0)
    {
        struct dirent *dirp;
        while ((dirp = readdir(dirh)) != 0)
        {
            char *str = malloc(dlen + strlen(dirp->d_name));
            if (str != 0)
            {
                struct stat buf;
                strcpy(str, mydir);
                strcat(str, dirp->d_name);
                if (stat(str, &buf) == 0)
                {
                    struct passwd *pwd = getpwuid(buf.st_uid);
                    if (pwd != 0)
                        printf("\t%s (%s)\n", str, pwd->pw_name);
                }
                free(str);
            }
        }
        closedir(dirh);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*Note:* The calculation of `dlen` is correct, but only because the value of `mydir` includes the trailing slash.  If the directory name did not include that trailing slash, the code would need changes to the length calculation and to formatting the composite name (the `strcpy()` `strcat()` sequence).  Beware!

Answer (score 4):

```
ptr=(char *)malloc(sizeof(strlen(mydir)));
ptr=strdup(mydir);
```

looks problematic at best :-)

You're allocating some memory in the first then leaking it when you allocate more memory in the second.

Even if that weren't a problem, I've never seen the paradigm:

```
sizeof(strlen(mydir))
```

You would tend to either use `sizeof` or `strlen()+1` when calling `malloc`. I think what you have, even if it worked, would simply allocate enough space for a `size_t`, the return value from `strlen`. I could be wrong on that count but I don't think it's relevant since you're not using that memory anyway due to the leak.

There are other problems such as:

- `getpwuid` is supposed to return a `struct passwd *` which you're ignoring.
- `strdup` gives you a copy of a string that is *exactly* the right size, then you `strcat` on to it, almost certainly corrupting memory.

Now this is untested but I think it's probably a better starting position:

```
struct stat buf;
struct dirent * direntp;
struct passwd * pwdp
for (direntp = readdir(dirh); direntp != NULL; direntp = readdir(dirh)) {
    // Allocate enough space for directory, separator, file and nul character.

    ptr = (char*)malloc (strlen(mydir) + 1 + strlen (direntp->d_name) + 1);

    strcpy (ptr, mydir);
    strcat (ptr,"/");
    strcat (ptr, direntp->d_name);

    stat(ptr, &buf);
    //modos();

    pwdp = getpwuid (buf.st_uid);
    printf("\t%s\n",ptr);  // prob. need something from pwdp printed here as well.

    // Don't leak.    
    free (ptr);
}

closedir(dirh);
```

Comment: If your OS provides `fstatat()`, then you don't need to build the pathname - you can just do `fstatat(dirfd(dirh), direntp->d_name, &buf, 0)`